# using autohotkey to get information about controls or widgets in a window

Tags: autohotkey

I was inspired by projects like  Vimium and Vimperator which are used to navigate web pages very fast by follwings hints to links which can be entered easily through keyboard.

Now , I want to extend this system to virtually every windows app for selecting controls or widgets like button, editbox, checkbox, radiobox etc. entirely through keyboard just like vimium. so, my question is can we use autohotkey to get informmation about controls in a window? Any ideas and suggestions are welcome. Also, if you know a project or app which already has this functionality please share it.Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Open the AHK Windows Spy, right click on ahk icon. Then hover your mouse over an object. You will see the object data under the header "Now under mouse Cursor".

Here is an example with NotePad, Save As, hovering over the [Save] button.

[image]